Angular signals: Template displays both "if" and "else" content
I have a strange issue within my Angular application.
In my component, I have a signal for loading and a data which is fetched with HTTPClient:
loading = signal(false);

competition = toSignal(
    this.competitionId$.pipe(
      switchMap(id => this.competitionService.getCompetitionById(id)
        .pipe(tap((v) => {
          this.loading.set(false)
          console.log('loaded', v)
        }))
      ),
      catchError(err => this.handleFetchError(err)),
    ),
    { initialValue: undefined }
  );

This is the only place where "loading" is modified.
In the template, I wanted to check it works with:
@if(loading()) {
  Loading ...
} @else {
  Loaded !
}


But strangefully, "Loaded !" is always displayed while "Loading ..." disappears when the data is actually loaded.

I suppose this comes from SSR, but I don't find how to fix that.
Thank you for your help
Additional informations: I have two errors I cannot fix, since the begining of the development:
One in the server console:

One in the browser console:


Solution 1:
Wrap your HTML inside a defer conditional block, this will ensure the content is only rendered on the browser, this might fix your issue.
Angular Docs - Defer
  @defer() {
    @if(loading()) {
      Loading ...
    } @else {
      Loaded !
    }
  }


Solution 2:
My Alternative solution is to use isPlatformBrowser to determine if you are rendering on the server and the rxjs operator filter will filter out the observable, so that the action does not happen on the server. I have also provided another simpler solution of checking if the window object is defined, then we are on the browser.
loading = signal(false);
platformId = inject(PLATFORM_ID);
isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId);

competition = toSignal(
    this.competitionId$.pipe(
      filter(() => typeof window !== 'undefined'),
      // filter(() => this.isBrowser),
      switchMap(id => this.competitionService.getCompetitionById(id)
        .pipe(tap((v) => {
          this.loading.set(false)
          console.log('loaded', v)
        }))
      ),
      catchError(err => this.handleFetchError(err)),
    ),
    { initialValue: undefined }
  );


Thank you for your answer, both solutions are working. Am I loosing the advantages of server side rendering ? It seems that if I disable javascript, no data is received by the app.

@AulomaI I think the API is not getting called in server, do you have some auth token required for the API to work, if you store the token in localstorage it does not exist in the server, yes, the content in the else block does not render on the server, that's all, few scenarios require this fix, mostly due to the loading flag not being set on the server
